# Numbering table of contents for Gitbook

Tags: tableofcontents, gitbook

I want to number the table of contents for a book processed by gitbook but cannot figure out how to do this.  If I use the Gitbook editor, there is a preference to see the numbering while editing, but I cannot see the numbering when creating an html version of the book.

I know it is possible to do so: the table of contents (sidebar) of https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/documentation/content/format/chapters.html
is numbered. By comparison, the one for https://toolchain.gitbook.com/ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is no longer set up by default and the following needs to be added do book.json, when using the default theme:

```
"pluginsConfig": {
    "theme-default": {
        "showLevel": true
    }
}
```